# Is SQL Server Express compatible for developing online - offline desktop application?

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application, sql-server-express

I'm trying to build a desktop application using electron, which will be online first app, where the data needs to be synced from the live server to the local database.

I want to use SQL Server Express as the local offline database. Previously I tried to connect SQLite with Electron. I was able to successfully create a connection and work without any problem, but it is a file-based database, but in the case of SQL Server Express, I don't think it is file based system like SQLite.

I did some research about it, it's saying that SQL Server Express can be changed to file-based DB, but it must be used only in dev environment, I want to create the SQL Server Express database in the client system locally and create the same table structures as online server, when the user installs my electron application.

This system will online first, after installing and logging, I want to sync the online data into the offline database.

Comment: You can use SQL Express locally. It needs to be installed as a separate installation. SQL Server LocalDb is a lighter form of the same. Not sure what you mean about "file based db" all databases use files. There is no "change" you can make. As far as syncing: just backup and restore the other database to the local machine.